# How do I get Excel 2013 to recalc the used extents of a worksheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

Using Excel 2013, how do I force a recalculation of the last used cell in the worksheet? For example, Ctrl + Shift + End selects a bunch of cells, as expected, but it also selected some blank cells.

The worksheets were created by copying an existing worksheet that had data in the now blank cells.The cells were cleared by pressing Delete and now I'm unable to get the real extents of the data in worksheet.

Comment: Can you not just delete the actual rows? That should remove all sign of them.

Comment: The old data is already gone and replaced with new data. However, the new data occupies less rows. Deleting the rows seems like an extra step I shouldn't need to perform.

Comment: Deleting the rows and then saving the workbook seemed to fix the issue. I guess I could look at creating a utility to delete all empty rows between the last row containing data and what Excel sees as the end of the UsedRange.

Comment: I have added it as an answer. I would appreciate you accepting my answer as it works. :0

Answer (score 2):

Try this-

1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>
3. Type `ActiveSheet.UsedRange` and press enter
4. Exit the VBA editor and re-save the workbook

Brief explanation of why it works ([Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa141370%28v=office.10%29.aspx))

> Every Worksheet object has a UsedRange property that returns a Range
>   object representing the area of a worksheet that is being used. The
>   UsedRange property represents the area described by the farthest
>   upper-left and farthest lower-right nonempty cells in a worksheet and
>   includes all cells in between.

You're forcing excel to "re-map" the `usedrange`.

Comment: Is formatting, e.g. a custom number format applied to a cell, taken into account when Excel determines the UsedRange?

Comment: @Scott Yes, it is included, if this doesn't work, delete the rows below your data. Also, see [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423022/excel-getting-the-actual-usedrange)

Comment: So that's my problem. I deleted the values in my selected range using the Delete key but the formatting remained. Actually deleting the rows (right-click, then select Delete) wiped out the entire row and its cells, formatting included.

Comment: @Scott correct. You can also use the shortcut Alt,E,D

Answer (score 1):

Even though the contents have been deleted it appears that the rows contain info that is included when you try. Just delete the actual rows. That should remove all formatting and allow you to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I have had many scenarios where deleting the rows in the "usedrange" below the data does not redefine the "usedrange" to only where data exists. In these cases, I create a new worksheet, and transfer the data to it. Then delete the previous worksheet with the problematic "usedrange".

Comment: It appears that your answer is incomplete as it does not answer the question completely. I looked through the other answers and it appears that in its current state, yours should be a comment to the answer by **Raystafarian**. Please expand your answer or delete and make it a comment as I indicated.